# IronPython Package "System.UnauthorizedAccessException" when updating config.ini

Tags: python, .net, windows, config, ironpython

I am building an IronPython package that contains a config.ini file in the package directory. The config file is used to maintain user settings but when I try to update the file I get a permissions error:

```
IOError: System.IO.IOException: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\...\_config.ini'
```

I have seen answers to similar questions which, for the most part, suggest running the command line as admin or using `error='ignore` with open.

```
with open(Paths.config_path, 'w+', errors='ignore') as configfile:
```

I don't want to tell my colleagues to run either the cmd.exe or their IDE as admin to use the package. I also don't want to just ignore the error and not update their settings. The basic structure worked fine for a similar CPython project and I would like to re-use the idea here. Is there a way to work around this?

In case it makes a difference:

- I am building the package with `ipy setup.py bdist_wheel`
- I use the MANIFEST.in to include the file. `recursive-include proj *.ini`

The setup file:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from prost import _meta

setup(name='...',
      version=_meta.__version__,
      packages=find_packages(),
      include_package_data=True,
      package_data={'prost': [r'bin/*.*', r'_config.ini']})
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Changed:

```
ipy -m pip install --upgrade my..-1.0.0.2-py2-none-any.whl
```

to

```
ipy -X:Frames -m pip install --upgrade dist\my..-1.0.0.2-py2-none-any.whl
```

and it worked.

Comment: Tried -X:Frames before posting the question and still had the issue. I am guessing it has since worked because there was some separate issue with my environment setup the first time around.